# Memory leak on methodSignatureForSelector

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I have the following code that gives me a leak when I analyze the generations using the instruments allocation tool.

```
SEL sel = NSSelectorFromString(self.selector);

NSInvocation* invocation = [ NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[ self.target methodSignatureForSelector:sel ] ];

[ invocation setTarget:self.target ];
[ invocation setSelector:sel ];

[ invocation invoke ];
```

The code does not check for return values.  There are a few invocations that will return objects but these are simply ignored.

The leak points to the invocation of [ NSMethodSignature methodSignatureForSelector ].  The stack shows a calloc call within this function that is leaking 48 bytes.

As, I am using ARC my assumption was that these buffers would be garbage collected automatically.  Yet there is a leak.   The last symbolic function closest to the top of stack in the allocations tool is

```
+[ NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes ]
```

These are called thousands of time during the code execution and the leaks are piling up.  Any help to track this down would be appreciated.

My process:
I used Instruments - Allocations, checked for ref counting, and then ran two generations. The Allocations tool allows you to drill down into a generation and then pick a buffer that was alloc'd (and not freed) during the generation and then you can drill down into the buffer see its ref counting history. If the last entry has a ref count then you might have a leak. Now one only needs to infer if there are strong cycles that are causing this object to leak.

Comment: Do you really need to use `NSInvocation`? Is there more to your code? As shown, you don't pass any arguments or use the return value so there is no reason to use `NSInvocation`.

Comment: I removed the arguments just for brevity as I thought they are not relevant to the leak.  There are different arguments that are picked up from a file and passed using setArguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the thread referred to by @Basheer_CAD, I changed all of the NSInvocations that were returning an object to now return void.  But it made no difference to the leaks. Also the allocation tool seemed to point distinctly at methodForSignature as the culprit and not the return value of the invocation.  Then, I decided to run a few more generations and now noticeably the leaks got less. On the 3rd generation there were no more leaks. So it appears that this leak has nothing to do with whether there is a returned object of the NSInvocation.  It appears that the methodSignatureForSelector is allocating a buffer of 48 bytes, and this buffer is cached against the Class object.  The cache possibly services repeated calls for the same method signature. I am going to disregard this leak because it does not show up after a few generations, and going to count it against some kind of cache build up.
So if these leak shows up the best way to resolve it is to run a few more generations until it fails to show up any more.

Comment: Thank you for publishing your findings

Answer (score 1):

The compiler complains about memory leak but you are not leaking memory here if the selector returns void. check out this [discussion](http://memeory%20leaks%20with%20peroform%20selector)

Try to use this:

```
[self.target performSelector:sel object:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

Comment: I looked through the discussion earlier.  But the compiler is not flagging any warnings for me.  I thought it might have to do with the return objects not being deallocated, but then why would it flag the methodSignatureForSelector call as having the offending calloc.  It points explicitly to inside of this call itself.

Comment: did you try performSelector ?

Comment: I have not used performSelector, because I need the flexibility of adding in variable arguments depending on the selector and that is offered by NSInvocation setArgument.  Would performSelector give better warnings?

Comment: well, performSelector gives you the opportunity to pass up to 2 args, but it is easier and less error prone. How did you find the leak and what object exactly leaks

Comment: That said I am going to try to remove the returns and see if the leak goes away.  It will take me sometime to have the results but I will share them.  Though I don't know why the allocations tool would flag a wrong calloc as the offender unless for some reason the NSInvocation gets the Allocations tool all confused.

Comment: can you update your question so we can see where the return value is ? @nishant

Comment: I used Instruments - Allocations, checked for ref counting, and then ran a couple of generations till it was stable.  Then Allocations allows you to drill down into a generation and then pick a buffer that was alloc'd (and not freed) during the generation and then you can drill down into the buffer see its ref counting history.  And so you can identify if you have strong graph cycles into your objects.